# How to import netty to eclipse without pom errors?

Tags: eclipse, maven, netty

I want to learn the source code of netty, and I import the source code of netty from [github](https://github.com/netty/netty.git), I use maven to import these code but there are some pom errors here when I import the project:

[image]

**I searched the Internet but I can't get any useful information.So I have nothing to do but to ask for help.**

ps,

I attempt to follow the steps [here](http://netty.io/wiki/setting-up-development-environment.html):

and the solution is :

> Set up Eclipse with M2E and Java 7/8
>   Ensure to use the 64-bit version of Eclipse.
>   Download os-maven-plugin and put it into /plugins (Eclipse 4.5) or /dropins (Eclipse 4.6) directory to work around the problem where m2e does not evaluate an extension specified in our pom.xml. (Unlike its name, it's both a Maven plugin and an Eclipse plugin.)
>   Import the project via the 'File → Import... → Existing Maven Projects' menu.
>   Netty project Maven pom.xml settings dictate use of Java SE 1.6, while implicitly using Java 7/8 (1.7/1.8) features if present. This may result in compilation errors in Eclipse. There are two ways to work around this problem:
>   Look in the 'Window → Preferences → Installed JRE' menu:
>   Make sure you have Java 7/8 installation available under 'Installed JRE'
>   Map this Java 7/8 installation onto Java 6: 'Installed JRE → Execution Environments → Java SE 1.6'
>   Alternatively, Java 7/8 JRE can be selected on per-project basis for each Netty module.

**I follow these steps but I cant't solve this problem.
could you please help me to solve this problem? I look forward to your help.**

- my OS information: 
  ProductName:    Mac OS X 
  ProductVersion: 10.13.3
  BuildVersion:   17D102
- my jdk information:
  java version "1.8.0_131"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
- my eclipse information:
  [image]
- my maven information:
  Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T03:39:06+08:00)
  Maven home: /Users/mingxing/development/tools/apache-maven-3.5.0
  Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
  Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view, just right-click the cloned repository (you can drop the GitHub URL on your Eclipse IDE to clone it) and choose _Import Projects..._. No changes should have been made before the import. So if you already cloned the Git repository, do a hard reset before _Import Projects..._.

Comment: @howlger thank you. I follow your step.first, I clone the GitHub url to my eclipse IDE, and it shows maven error window, I closed the window. second, I right-click the cloend repository and do a hard reset. The third, I click Import Projects...  but when I click select all , I can't select any of them and the next button is grey. What should I do now?

Comment: You also have to delete the already imported projects first to start from scratch.

Comment: thank you ,I'll have a try.